# Ruby on Rails, How to reset a counter every day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I need to save a reference number every time I save a record of a certain model, the reference should be composed of 10 numbers, the first 8 numbers are related to the creator id and date, but the last 2 digits should be an incremental number starting at 00 and ending at 99, this count should be reset every single day.

For example:

```
Records created the same day:
SD01011800
GF01011801
MT01011802
...
GH01011899
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Records created the next day:
SD02011800
GF02011801
MT02011802
...
GH02011899
```

Where the first 2 letters are the initials of a name, the next 2 are the current day, next 2 current month, next 2 current year, next 2 incremental number (from 0 to 99, reset daily)

Also every reference HAS TO be unique.
I'm missing the last two digits part, any idea on how to grant this ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: are you certain that you won't create more than 100 (00-99) objects in a day?

Comment: Is this a pre-existing hard requirement? For example, is it the ID format required for some other system you're talking to? If not, there's probably a better way to handle whatever problem this is trying to solve. Like [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: @JoshBrody yes, that requirement was given by the stakeholders.

Comment: @SebastianDelgado Can you convince them otherwise? This is a poor engineering choice.

Comment: Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Since it looks like nobody pointed it out directly. If multiple people have the same initials they will share the max 100 updates per day. For all letters A-Z (26 letters) and the 100 updates maximum 26 * 26 * 100 = 67600 is the maximum number of writes when utilizing _all_ the initials for a whole day. So since unique, that is the maximum number of writes throughout the whole system for a single day. Since there are only 676 unique pair of initials it would have to be a fairly small system for this to not turn into an issue for you.

Comment: @Schwern, I'm trying to persuade them NOT to do this the way they originally wanted it to be but they just keep insisting

Comment: @CodyGustafson It's worse. According to the example there's only one daily counter shared between all records regardless of prefix. 100 new records per day.

Comment: @SebastianDelgado Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Where the first 2 letters are the initials of a name, the next 2 are the current day, next 2 current month, next 2 current year, next 2 incremental number (from 0 to 99, reset daily).*

[As folks in the comments have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956254/ruby-on-rails-how-to-reset-a-counter-every-day#comment90863151_51956254), this assumes there is a maximum of 100 entries per day, and it will have problems in 2100. One is more pressing than the other. Maybe if you go over 100 you can start using letters?

> *Also every reference HAS TO be unique.*

For globally unique identifiers [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_2_(date-time_and_MAC_address,_DCE_security_version))s, Universally Unique IDentifiers, are generally the way to go. If you can change this requirement it would be both simpler (databases already support UUIDs), more robust (UUIDs aren't limited to 100 per day), and more secure (they don't leak information about the thing being identified).

---

Assuming you can't change the requirement, the next number can be gotten by adding up the number of existing rows that day.

```
select count(id)
from stuff
where date(created_at) == date(NOW());
```

However there is a problem if two processes both insert a new record at the same time and get the same next number. Probably highly unlikely if you're expecting only 100 a day, but still possible.

```
Process 1                   Process 2                  Time

select count(id) ...                                   1
                            select count(id) ...       2
insert into stuff ...                                  3
                            insert into stuff...       4
```

A transaction won't save you. You could get an exclusive lock on the whole table, but that's dangerous and slow. Instead you can use [an advisory lock](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock) for this one operation. Just make sure all code which writes new records uses this same advisory lock.

```
Stuff.with_advisory_lock(:new_stuff_record) do
  ...
end
```

---

Alternatively, store the daily ID in a column. Add a database trigger to add 1 on insert. Set it back to 0 with a scheduled job at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your class is named `Record` and it has an attribute called `reference_number`.

If that is the case, you can use the following method to fetch the two last digits.

```
def fetch_following_two_last_digits
  if Record.last.created_at < Time.current.beginning_of_day
    "00"
  else
    (Record.last.reference_number.last(2).to_i + 1).to_s
  end
end
```

Also assuming you never reach 100 records a day. Otherwise, you'd end up having three last digits.

Comment: This is basically what I wrote. It's vulnerable to race conditions.